# I receive "TypeError: items is undefined" when trying to map items from a JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently trying to setup a React web app using React hooks. I try to pull the items from the JSON with Map but I receive this error.

TypeError: items is undefined

Shop.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import './App.css';

function Shop() {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItems();
    }, []);

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchItems = async () => {
        const data = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get');

        const items = await data.json();
        console.log(items.items);
        setItems(items.items);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {items.map(item => (
                <h1>{item.map}</h1>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Shop;
```

Comment: Why are you using .json(); when I open the response it looks like a deserialised JSON already? It also looks like data.items is not the correct data structure.

should just be setItems(items);

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `items` and not `items.items`? Or, what if you `console.log(items)`?

Answer (score 1):

### I've tried on my end and confirmed it works.

Let me show the codes.

```
function Shop() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get');

    const deserialisedResponse = await response.json();
    console.log("result: ", deserialisedResponse)

    setItems(deserialisedResponse.data);
  };


  return (
      <div>
        {items.map((item, idx) => (
          <h1 key={idx}>{item.item.name}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
  )
}
```

### Please have a check and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on React, but I'm pretty sure its because you get to the return statement before you define items.

That function is async, so while it takes its turn running each line, the program itself will move on, thus getting to the return with "items" in it before items is actually defined.

What might fix it is doing an if/else that checks if items is defined, then returns either blank html or the html with items.  React dynamically updates so that should then return the correct html once items is loaded.

Comment: He has defined it as an empty array when he declared the useState variable

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your question. I have checked the response from the GET request you provided and you have used the incorrect data structuring when pulling fields out. Try the code below.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import './App.css';

function Shop() {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItems();
    }, []);

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchItems = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get');

        const deserialisedResponse = await response.json();

        setItems(deserialisedResponse.data);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <h1 key={index}>{item.map}</h1>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Shop;
```

Comment: I've tried your comment and there is no more error. I did use "items && items.map" as well. I get no output on the page though.

Comment: can you log the response.data above in the fetchItems and show a snippet of what is returned

Comment: It looks two lines of,

async function fetchItems()
​
length: 0
​
name: "fetchItems"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
constructor: function AsyncFunction()
​​
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "AsyncFunction"
​​
<prototype>: function ()

Comment: Sorry I don't understand where did you log. It looks like you logged the actual fetch function and not the response.

Comment: `response.json()` is necessary, as it reads the response stream to completion and returns JSON: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: Could be my bad I usually use axios where this hasn't been required I will update code above.

* Have updated to include the .json() function

Comment: I added the updates and the page loads. There is still no header though. I get "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: I have updated the code to resolve the key issue but it is not recommended practice to use the index. Have a read of the react documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html